# How to deploy Rails apps on a single VM using Cloud66

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, digital-ocean, cloud66

I'm quite new to docker containers and curious about the proper way to deploy them.

I have a couple of Rails apps that are ready for deployment. 4 to be exact. Each app needs each other to work. I have a Cloud66 and a DigitalOcean account linked together. However, every time you deploy a new app from Cloud66, it will create a new droplet.

Is it possible to deploy my 4 Rails app using Cloud66 on a single droplet?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to run 4 stacks on 1 server.

There are two workarounds to consider:

1. Run the 4 Rails apps as engines and mount them into 1 rack application.
2. Create a docker stack on a 1 VM and run 4 Rails apps as docker containers.